# How can I collect id into list according to relation column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I have a dataframe like:

```
  id near_relation
0  A        [B, D]
1  B     [A, H, N]
2  C        [I, R]
3  D        [A, E]
4  E        [D, M]
5  F        [J, K]
6  J        [F, P]
7  P        [J, S]
```

I want to collect `id` into a list based on neighboring relationships `near_relation` column. For example, `A` and `D` have neighboring relationships , `D` and `E` have neighboring relationships, so `A` and `E` should be collected in a list. So the results I expect are as follows:

```
        collect
0  [A, B, D, E]
1           [C]
2     [F, P, J]
```

I can do this with a loop, but my dataframe is big and I want a more elegant solution.

**Add Loop Solution**

```
def add(x,x_dict):
    tmp_list = x.copy()
    last_len = 0
    while len(tmp_list)!=last_len:
        current_len = len(tmp_list)
        for m in tmp_list[last_len:]:
            if m in x_dict.keys():
                for n in x_dict[m]:
                    if n not in tmp_list:
                        tmp_list.append(n)
        last_len = current_len
    return set(tmp_list) & set(x_dict.keys())

df_dict = df.set_index('id').to_dict()
df['collect'] = df['near_relation'].apply(lambda x: add(x,df_dict['near_relation']))
```

Then I grouped them according to the results of the above loops.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your loop solution as well?

Comment: What do you mean with `A and D have neighboring relationships`?

Comment: @yatu It means `A` and `D` have neighboring relationships that `D` is included in  `near_relation` when `id=A`.

Comment: Seems you have an undirected graph and you want to find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). If you have a very big dataset, you might also consider using a graph theory library instead.

Comment: @dangom I added it to the question.

Comment: @jdehesa You're right. Can you recommend some graph theory libraries and examples?

Comment: @giser_yugang For Python, I used [graph_tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) in the past and was quite happy with how fast it was (e.g. [`label_components`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html#graph_tool.topology.label_components)). [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) is a very popular one, maybe more accessible (see [Analyzing graphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#analyzing-graphs) example).

Comment: @jdehesa This is helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `NetworkX` approach. Start by getting all `id`-`near_relation` tuples, which will be used as edges to build the graph:

```
l = [(i.id,nb) for _, i in df.iterrows() for nb in i.near_relation]
# [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'H'), ('B', 'N')...
```

Build a graph from the above list of edges and compute its [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components). Finally keep only those components that also appear in the `id` column:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(l)
cc = nx.connected_components(G)
[i & set(df.id) for i in cc]
```

**Output**

```
[{'A', 'B', 'D', 'E'}, {'C'}, {'F', 'J', 'P'}]
```